# VS Code / C# / Unity - Everything becomes blue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

my vs code auto-updates to v1.82

then I noticed that most(90%) of the text becomes blue and unity functions and variables are not being recognized

for example: transform.gameObject <--- is not working anymore and not auto detecting by vs code like before..

I already reinstall the vs code and reimplement it in the edit>preference section of the unity, but the issues is still there.

I also tried installing old version lng 1.80 and 1.81 but the issue is still there..

Additional note:
even the .editorconfig

> ```
> "[*.{cs,vb}]
> dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Style.severity = none
> dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-CodeQuality.severity = none"
> ```

is not working anymore, it has solved my blueish Roslyn issue before.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: what do you see when you use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command and click around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be worth clearing your user settings.json file. If you're on windows it should be here: goto run and search "%APPDATA%" -> %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json.

Delete everything between the two `{}`

If it is not this you could have a look at your extensions list (ctrl + shift + x) to check if you have a unity snippets extension that has been turned off by the user?

It might be worth uninstalling all extensions you have installed to do with unity and look for up to date versions. Snippets go down all the time.

Comment: thanks I might try this, sorry for the late response, I eventually transferred using vs studio instead